# Prevent replay attacks with Public/Private Key-Encryption of HTTP GET Parameters using Mcrypt and PHP

Tags: php, http, mcrypt, replay

I want to create a a game application, for that i want the client to send to server scores and other information that should be encrypted.

I understood that there is a way with `mcrypt` to encrypt data with public and private keys. so the application on the client side will encrypt but I am the only one that will be able to decrypt it. I don't have much more information to go on, i just want to know the most secure way to paste data.

What I understood so far is this example:

if I have: `?username=foo&score=50&msg=hello`
I can encrypt it to: `msgencrypted=fgus9g8uywe978ygt7923y5235sdfdsadfsd` (example)

and only with a specific key that I have on my server I can decrypt it.

Again I'm just trying to find the best method to hide data from the user so he won't be able to decrypt it.

which means that if I encrypted a message... that message won't be able to be sent twice.

So if the user used firebug to see what a request was sent and tries to send it again, the message will be invalid. I guess I can just record it in a database. But if there is a method for such a thing it would be great.

I am using PHP 5.4.

Comment: This can be called an replay-attack. You probably were not aware of the term so far, so please search again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [PKI (public key infrastructure)](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/PKI). Public-key cryptography (AKA asymmetric cryptography) refers to a cryptographic algorithm which requires two separate keys (a key pair), one of which is secret (or private) and one of which is public key.

Your client has access to public key and encrypts message using public key and only server which has access to private key may decrypt the message. 
Let's say you may encrypt scores and other information with RSA algorithm and send it to server. This way you prevent [parameter-tampering](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/parameter-tampering). You may also use [MAC (Message Authentication Code)](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/message-authentication-code-MAC) to prevent tampering.

But I recommend to POST data instead of using GET; because usually URLs will be logged in web servers or ISPs. So its reasonable not to put confidential encrypted data in query strings.

To prevent replay attacks you may use a counter and send it along the parameters. at the server side you store the last counter's value (for example 123). When you get a request which its counter value is equal or less than the stored value you have to reject the request. e.g. when you get a request with counter values <=123.
Since you are encrypting all parameters no one may tamper the counter value too.

Actually POS terminals use a similar approach to prevent replay attacks. If you want higher levels of security try reading about POS transaction security and how transactions are secured against replay/man-in-the-middle attack.